# ErrorException flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a laravel web application that has some users and is working perfectly well.

But sometimes I have this error that Iam showing below :

```
ErrorException App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@errorLog flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given
```

and I have that folders with all permissions.

Like other  thread in stackoverflow:

```
chmod 775 storage/framework/cache

chmod 775 storage/framework/cache/data

sudo chgrp www-data storage/framework/cache

sudo chgrp www-data storage/framework/cache/data
```

I thought it would be more people accessing it at the same time and the file being locked. But in the users where this error happens they were just using it.

I cannot understand this situation.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I checked that post before.. But its not the same thing. BecauSe im using the laravel function for this :(

Comment: any one can help me?